# How can i give custom total count in array data provider for yii

Tags: php, yii

I used `CArrayDataProvider` for grid in yii, the issue is with that it takes first whole data then it gives limit in data provider which is taking too much time to load, so i wants to do custom total count in arraydata provider, i did some stuff fot that but it is giving me error, here is my code

```
$rawDataWithArray = $modelMemberreceipt->getMemberReceiptListWithLimit($searchString,$PageSize,$currentPage);
$filteredData=$filtersForm->filter($rawDataWithArray);
$rawDataCount = $modelMemberreceipt->getMemberReceiptListItemCount($searchString);

                $model = new CArrayDataProvider($rawDataWithArray, array( 
                            'keyField' => 'ReceiptID', 
                            'itemCount' => $rawDataCount,
                            'sort' => array(
                                'attributes' => array(
                                    'ReceiptID','StoreName','member','LoyaltyCardNo','MerchantTypeID',
                                    'ReceiptAmount','ReceiptDate','Status','Created','Updated','RejectionReasonCode','ProcessingReason',
                                    'UpdatedBy','ScannedReceiptNo'
                                ),
                                'defaultOrder' => $sortArray,
                            ),
                            'pagination' => array(
                            'pageSize' => $PageSize,
                            'currentPage'=>$currentPage,
                        ),
                ));
```

For $rawDataWithArray i set the limit so it will give records like 10, for $rawDataCount i set the total count, for both the variable i am getting the proper data so no issue with the data, when i set the itemCount it is giving me error `Property "CArrayDataProvider.itemCount" is read only.`, can anyone please tell me how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemCount` Returns the number of data items in the current page. It will be calculated autamaticaly.
I think you need to set `totalItemCount` instead of `itemCount`:

`'totalItemCount' => $rawDataCount,`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider